# Closure of the preimage of an open set

Tags: general-topology

Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ and standard topology. Let $O\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be an open set. Under what conditions we have:
$$
cl(f^{-1}(O))=f^{-1}(cl(O))
$$

Comment: [Is the preimage of the closure the closure of the preimage under a quotient map?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74415/is-the-preimage-of-the-closure-the-closure-of-the-preimage-under-a-quotient-map) contains a proof of "**For an open continuous map $f\colon X\to Y$, $\overline{f^{-1}(S)}=f^{-1}(\overline{S})$ for all $S\subset Y$.**"